# Is there any difference in using smtps instead of smtp?

Tags: comparison, smtp, smtps

Or is it transparent for the application layer ?

I ask this because I'm trying to connect to a smtps and no success
(smtp is working fine)

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information about the environment you're doing this in: language, libraries, server, settings, code, ...

Comment: Ok, This is a local test and I'm using PHP.
But I don't think these informations make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to wikipedia it's transparent to the application layer, since its
no protocoll and no smtp-extension. It does it job perfectly transparent on
the transport layer.

K

Comment: something might be wrong on my ssl configuration then. thanks